# IIS Hanging. Bizarre Callstack: Unknown MethodDesc

Tags: iis, windbg, freeze

I am having general hangs on our IIS application pool. Sometimes, when I get a Crash Dump, I get one thread which is blocking all the others and that has no call stack:

```
ESP       EIP     
4735e1dc 7c82860c [NDirectMethodFrameStandalone: 4735e1dc] Unknown MethodDesc (Module 1f3363e8, mdToken 0600016c)
```

I looked over the Internet but I did not find anything similar. Does it mean I have corrupted memory.

Comment: How did you came to the conclusion that this thread blocks all of the other threads in the process? Perhaps if you'll provide the stack traces for the other threads as well (native+managed), it will be easier the investigate the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with dump analysis, feel free to open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com.

Though SO is good for technical questions, but dump analysis is more of an art.